# Login form using javafx and file reading

Tags: java, javafx, filereader, scenebuilder

I am new to javafx and i need to design a GUI that asks for username and password from the user. Whatever combination of username and password the user enters, needs to be verified from a text file on clicking the submit button. If the credentials are incorrect, a label stating "Incorrect Credentials" must appear, resetting the text-fields. Once the user enters correct credentials, the scene should navigate to a Welcome Screen.

How should I proceed?

Comment: you have to try to do it yourself. read some documentation and tutorials about JavaFX and reading from a file in java. code it, and if you have any specific problem with your code, you may ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

Begin with tutorials, as you are completely new I would suggest using this tutorial as a starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm

If you are using an IDE such as eclipse, have a look at SceneBuilder. It will allow you to build a GUI by drag and dropping elements. Here is a download for the newest verison of SceneBuilder http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/